# How to think about a schedule-building script (general thought process)

Tags: python, schedule

I ran into this issue that's been bugging me.
I'm trying to write a Python script to build a stock take schedule.

I managed to propose dates based on deadlines and I also managed to move the proposed dates to the nearest "legal" date in case the original proposed date fell on weekend, planned annual code freeze, etc...

I've got couple more conditions and I'm struggling to implement those.
I tried a combination of while loops with ifs, but it got me nowhere in my case.

I'm a self-taught Pythoner who's been mostly using Pandas for analysis until now, that's why I'm probably struggling with this.
**
I'm not looking for a free code service**, but I'd be over the moon if someone could give me a nudge how to think about this issue in the first place.

Ideally the dates the algorithm comes with will be:

1. Before given deadline for each location
2. No more than n counts happening on the same date
   and I could possibly swap the last one around manually, but:
3. No location from the same area to be on the same date

| Area | Location | Deadline | Proposed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | 14 Apr | 01 Apr |
| B | B3 | 14 Apr | 01 Apr |
| A | A2 | 14 Apr | 03 Apr |

Any little nudge in the right direction or a half line of pseudocode would be a great help.

Massive thanks to anyone who hasn't gone into Picard-style facepalm yet after reading this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start with pseudocode.

Something like this:

```
For entry in your data.
   Propose an initial date (eg: deadline -1)
   Check if another location from the same area happens that day
     Yes?  Decrement 1 to the proposed day and check again
     No?  Check the next condition
  Check that if more than n counts happen on this date
     Yes?  Decrement 1 to the proposed day and check again both conditions
     No?  Set the date for that entry.
```

How you do the checkings will depend how you decide to store your data. I'd suggest probably dictionaries, but maybe you might need to crete your own classes and data structures.

Of course this is a simple algorithm that might not be able to fit all dates, but is something you can start with. Then if you see it's not enough you can try adding some things, like sorting your entries, so the most restrictive ones are set first and the more flexible ones are set last.

Ideally it should be implemented as a tree where you explore branches and can backtrack once stuck, so you would eventually find a path that leads to all entries having a solution. Trees however can grow too much to be computable, so you would need some heuristics to explore some branches first. But this can get too complex, so maybe for your problem a simpler algorithm like the one I proposed will work good enough

Comment: Thanks so much for this - exactly what i needed!
Am I correct to assume that I should hide this in a while loop?

'while 1 or more of these conditions are not met:
     check if date in legal date
     .......'

Comment: My code uses a for loop that iterates every entry, so you don't need a while loop. Start making something simple like this, and then feed it with data containing few entries that capture the cases you want to check. Calculate manually the result and check line by line that your code does what you expect to do. Then incrementally add more data and see that it still solves the problem. If it gets stuck understand why and think how you could solve it. Once you have a working program, feel free to post code if it gives problems.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. For loop is actually a nicer solution than the clumsy while loop I tried previously!